# Flutter App Signing / Google Signing causing debugging issues

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have an app on the Play Store that was Signed by Google, the problem is when I start running `flutter run --release`.

When I already have it installed from the store, it uninstalls the Google app version deleting the database within the app, and installs the app as a completely fresh install.

This causes me issues, as sometimes I get issues with the production not existing on the self-signed app, like SQLite database migrations ...etc

so my question is how to correct that?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is signed by Google and running "flutter run --release" causes the signatures to be inconsistent,leading to re-install the app.If you want to keep it consistent, you can upgrade your Google signature to be the same as your local signature.

Comment: And how to do that? or how to do the opposite, how to make my local signature same as google?